# How to get logo, header and button in line without using margin hack.

Tags: css

I want a heading, a logo and a button to all be in line where the heading is centered, the logo is offset to it's right and the button is small on the right hand side.

I can hack this together if I fix the margins but this is not scalable and therefore don't want it as a final solution. What's a better way to do this?

My code is below and I also have it posted here as well: http://codepen.io/blueduckyy/pen/RpKoMJ .

HTML:

```
  <div class="top-bar username-heading">
      <img src="http://www.wonko.info/ipt/xfiles/interfaces/target.bmp" alt="Missing">
      <h1>blueduckyy</h1>
      <a class="button user-edit-button" href="/users/edit">Edit</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.username-heading img {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:-250px;
  margin-right:150px;
}

.username-heading h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.username-heading {
  height: 120px;
  background: yellow;
}

.user-edit-button {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
```

Comment: You can use `flexbox`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the items with 'position: absolute' inside the container:

```
.username-heading {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: static;
}
.username-heading img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.username-heading h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.username-heading {
  height: 120px;
  background: yellow;
}

.user-edit-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 120px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Keep in mind that the '.username-heading' position must be other than 'static'.

Answer (score 0):

Just use positioning,

```
position: relative;
top: 25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only css youll need.... Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/Bogdan986/pen/mWRmgQ?editors=1100)

```
 .top-bar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: orangered;
}
img{
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: img css is optional... you can style it as you wish... :)

Comment: also,you should use prefixes for diferent browsers(webkit,moz etc),cuz flexbox is still not supported 100%...

Comment: How do I move the img inbetween the header and the edit button? That's where I found the most difficulty.

Comment: .top-bar>h1{order: -1;} Here is the link for the video tutorial on flexbox... Its all explaned in the details by this Wes guy... I stopped using floats and positioning  :D         https://flexbox.io/

Comment: and... its great for media queries... here is a link ehere you can learn more about that: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/patterns#mostly_fluid